# Need to provide underline below accesskey for button in jsf 1.2

Tags: jsf-1.2

Need to provide underline below accesskey for button in jsf 1.2
Suppose access key is CTRL+SHIFT+S and button text is Submit, So only below S there should be underline.
Please help how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility of doing the thing so straight forward, but there are several work arround of the problem. Here is two of them:

```
 1.You can do it using background image in Button.
 2. You can write a javascript function to underline the desired text of the button 
    and call the function in onload event of the html body.
```

Cheers and happy coding!